# My website does not execute other requests when running Ajax Loop

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem executing multiple ajax requests.
While this process is running, access to my website is rejected or very slow.
Once this process is completed, the website returns to normal and accepts requests.

My code is basically the following, and it takes 5 to 20 minutes depending on the iterations, during this time my website does not respond
I am using JQUERY and Laravel 10

```
for (let i = 0; i < rfcs.length; i++) {

  promises.push(
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "/reports/exam",
      data: $.param(frm),
    })
  );

}
```

I think it may be due to the number of simultaneous requests and that it must be a configuration of the Apache server.

Is there a way to limit multiple ajax requests, without making the process synchronous?

Comment: How often do you need to execute these requests?  Maybe something like `setInterval` instead of just firing off all of them at once?  It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish by sending multiple identical requests like this in the first place.

Comment: Your code doesn't make a lot of sense to me. I've never sent identical ajax requests in a loop like this

Comment: Could perhaps also be the common problem with session file locking. In that case, calling session_write_close as soon as possible in the processing of those AJAX requests might(!) help a bit.